# A background service that will wait for items to process without busy-waiting

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Problem space: I have the concept of a `Job` that needs to be processed. Jobs need to be processed sequentially, as one may depend on another. It's possible for a Job to be paused, in which case the next Job should *not* be started - the Job should either be explicitly continued, or cancelled, in order to get the next one to start.

If the background service doing these Jobs finishes, it should wait for an update to a RESTful resource before trying to start processing again. I don't want the service to busy-wait.

```
public class ExecutionBackgroundService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IJob _job;
    private readonly AutoResetEvent _isRunning = new AutoResetEvent(true);

    public ExecutionBackgroundService(IJob job)
    {
        _job = job;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        // Required for the method to be executed asynchronously, allowing startup to continue.
        await Task.Yield();
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            _isRunning.WaitOne(); // blocks the thread, waiting for the event to be set by something else calling the Resume method
            await _job.Process();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Notifies the background service to resume processing.
    /// </summary>
    public void Resume()
    {
        _isRunning.Set();
    }
}
```

Jobs are represented by a DB entity. The `IJob` implementation looks something like this:

```
    public async Task Process()
    {
        using var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope();
        var database = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<MyDbContext>();
        var iterator = new DatabaseJobIterator(database);
        var worker = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IWorker>();
        while (iterator.HasNext())
        {
            await worker.DoLongRunningWork(iterator.Next);
        }
    }
```

Where the implementing class is singleton-scoped, and the DB and `IWorker` are both request-scoped (hence why I'm getting them using the scope factory).

`DatabaseJobIterator` is basically a simplified `IEnumerator` that just exposes two methods `HasNext` and `Next`, where `HasNext` will query the database for the oldest job, and assign it to `Next`. If the job is ready to be processed, it returns true. If the job is paused, it returns false.

An API controller that handles POSTs and PUTs to Jobs will then just call `Resume` on the background service, indicating that it might have new items to process if it isn't already running.

My question is whether I've used the `AutoResetEvent` correctly. Is there a more standard way to get the background service to wait without e.g. busy-waiting in a `while (true)` loop?

Comment: Are your API and your BackgroundService running in a same or in a separate process? In other words are we talking about cross-process synchronization or in-process?

Comment: Just out of interested: Who would be calling `Resume()` and how? Do you pass around references to the `ExecutionBackgroundService` instance to other components? How would you get those references in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest `SemaphoreSlim` instead of `AutoResetEvent` here because it has asynchronous API and will not block the current thread, and it accepts `CancellationToken`. `Task.Yield` is good hack but it can be useless because `await` in case of not `null` `SynchronizationContext` will restore the context and `WaitOne()` can anyway block the current thread.

```cs
public class ExecutionBackgroundService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IJob _job;
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1); // 1 is concurrency degree

    public ExecutionBackgroundService(IJob job)
    {
        _job = job;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                await _semaphore.WaitAsync(stoppingToken);
                await _job.Process();
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
        { } // occurs when WaitAsync receives canceling callback from the Token, you may log it if needed.
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Notifies the background service to resume processing.
    /// </summary>
    public void Resume()
    {
        lock (_semaphore)
        {
            if (_semaphore.CurrentCount == 0) // is it waiting now?
                _semaphore.Release();
        }
    }
}
```

This way is better because now you may cancel the Token without calling the `Resume()`.

Btw it's a programming pattern - **Producer/Consumer**. The best way for moving forward is using the specially designed for this purpose almost brand-new classes - `System.Threading.Channels`. Refer to this [link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/an-introduction-to-system-threading-channels/).

Comment: The implementation of `Resume` is not thread-safe, two or more threads can enter the if-statement concurrently.

Comment: @Johnbot good catch, thanks! Fixed.